# Crash reports from Microsoft Store for .NET Maui Apps

Tags: .net, windows-store-apps, maui, maui-blazor

I have a MAUI App in the Microsoft Store. It's using Blazor Hybrid, ie. most of the app is a web application running in a web view.

The store statistics tells me about "crashes" but doesn't tell me more. Help text on that page says that it's likely because I don't include symbols in the package.

I release in the debug configuration, no optimizations and I publish with

```
dotnet publish .\Squil.Maui -f net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0
```

(Side note: I can't publish in VS any longer since the newest VS update. It just says "1 failed" even though nothing in the logs indicate anything was wrong. The logs do indicate .NET 7 being involved though, which is weird as this is a .NET 6 project. This used to work until recently with somewhat different looking publish dialogs. The UI does and did include a checkbox for debug symbols, but I don't know what I need to do on the command line instead. It certainly didn't do the job back when I could publish with VS.)

The package does indeed not include any pdbs and the log complains about a missing tool:

```
C:\Users\jens\.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.1.3\buildTransitive\Microsoft.Build.Msix.Packaging.targets(341,
5): warning : Path to `mspdbcmf.exe` could not be found. A symbols package will not be generated.
```

After an hour of hunting I found the tool in the Visual Studio installation and what I need to do to make it being used: Adding this to my project file makes it being picked up:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MsPdbCmfExeFullpath>..\tools\MsPdbCmf.exe</MsPdbCmfExeFullpath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

(I copied the file into my project.)

The build log now says

```
Adding file 'Squil.Maui.pdb'.
```

but the msix package still doesn't contain it (so what was it added to!?).

Also, I get this message in the logs:

```
[Non FASTLINK] The input PDB file was not generated by the linker with /DEBUG:fastlink.
```

I've filed a [ticket with the MAUI repo](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11408).

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Did you try to debug the project to check if the application will crash on your device? In addition, can [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8637) on the github help you?

Comment: On my devices there are no crashes, no. Neither when install from the shop nor when debugging from VS. In the linked issue the OP basically did what I tried and says it "worked fine", but I bet he didn't look into the package to verify the pdbs are there or that he actually got infos on crash reports. MSBuild doesn't produce any warnings or errors in my case either, I had to increase the verbosity level to see the last two messages of the question above.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Also note that the "Path to `mspdbcmf.exe` could not be found." warning goes away as soon as you specify a path, even if the path doesn't exist. You need to use debug verbosity to verify that the tool is actually found.